# Why is myToken variable is always undefined?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, jwt

```
var fs = require('fs');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

var secret = fs.readFileSync('secret.key', 'utf8');

var myToken = jwt.sign({foo : 'bar'}, secret, {expiresInMinutes : 1440}, function(err, token) {
      console.log(token);
});
```

Here is my code. The problem is that `myToken` is always undefined. So, Where is the problem here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `asynchronously` way. So the token is got in the callback function, will not be returned by `jwt.sign` function.

```
jwt.sign({foo : 'bar'}, secret, {expiresInMinutes : 1440}, function(err, token) {
      console.log(token);
});
```

If you don't use asynchronously way, then it should be:

```
var myToken = jwt.sign({foo : 'bar'}, secret, {expiresInMinutes : 1440});
```

Chose either style but not both.